# How to add floating action button one by one in Linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, floating-action-button

I'm developing an attendance manager app. To take attendance , I've to create layout like this

[image]

I want to make it programatically. In the below layout I've used to add FAB using xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager to achieve that programatically, here some example:

http://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview

https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now  I have successfully implemented my work using recyclerview.

Answer (score 2):

GridLayout manger will do this favour for you. this automatically mange all floating buttons alignment and create as many as floating button you want

Comment: Can you give an example , about this ?

Comment: [example](http://androidexample.com/Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=75)

change  static final String[] numbers = new String[] with floatingbutton array and loop then or what ever you want to do